# R raster multiplication - why does the raster size increase tremendously

Tags: r, raster

I am working with MODIS raster-data in R (raster package) and I wonder, why the size of a raster becomes 7000 times larger when multiplying two raster files. In my case, one raster is a simple MODIS raster (values between 0 and 255 (integer)), the other one is kind of a template (0 and 1 (integer)). So I don't understand why the raster should be so large? It is a big problem when trying to save the raster with writeRaster, as my R session keeps crashing.

My code looks like this:

```
a <- list.files('All_MODIS_files_of_one_year.tif')
for (day in 1:length(a)){
ra <- raster(a[day])
ra_reduce <- ra * s
```

Object size of `ra` is 12064 bytes, object size of `s` is 11984 bytes. Object size of `ra_reduce` is 93777512 bytes. When I finally stack a whole year, the file becomes almost 40 GB large. :(

I tried the `round` function, tried to set the `@file@datanotation` to integer, but nothing helped. 
Has anyone an idea how to fix this?!

Answer (score 4):

The object size of the `ra` (and presumably also `s`) is very small because it does not have the cell values in memory. If you `show(ra)` you will see that the data are on disk (in a file). After multiplication the values will be in memory. You can avoid that by using a method such as `calc` or `overlay` that allows you to write the results to file, or by using `writeRaster`. That is:

```
x <- overlay(ra, s, fun=function(x,y){x*y}, filename='file.tif')
```

Or

```
ra_reduce <- ra * s
ra_reduce <- writeRaster(ra_reduce, filename='ra_reduce.tif')
```

To reduce file size you can (perhaps) use the `datatype` argument.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to write every file to disc (as .nc with compression = 9) and merged them afterwards. It worked and also now I know what caused the issue ;) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rasters increase in size depending on which format you save them. When you use the write raster function, you have to specify the data type of your output. If I'm not mistaken, by default it will save it as a float, which mean gigantic raster sizes. You can check if the raster is a float if the numbers show as "0.000000", for example.

So, to correct this you should do:

```
 a <- list.files('All_MODIS_files_of_one_year.tif')
 for (day in a){           #some optimization here, hope you don't mind
   ra <- raster(day)       #if you don't use length, the position of 'day' will be the name of the raster.
   ra_reduce <- ra * s
   writeRaster(ra_reduce, paste0("prefix_", day,".tif"), format = "GTiff", datatype = "INT1U", overwrite = TRUE)  
{
```

Basically, to correct this you only need to specify which data type you want to save your raster in. That's one of the parameters of the `writeRaster` function. The one I specified is the smallest data type I know for this function. Values will be intergers and it can vary from 0 to 256. You can check data type documentation for others.